# using pyowm getting the average tempature (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, weather-api

I would like to display the average tempture in my python code.

I found http://openweathermap.org/, with their API I made the following code:

```
import pyowm

api = pyowm.OWM('Your API key')
collectinfo = api.weather_at_place("Gorinchem,nl")
short = collectinfo.get_weather()
temperature = short.get_temperature('celsius')
print(temperature)
```

yet the tempature function displays multiple variables e.g.

> temp': 18.72, 'temp_max': 20.0, 'temp_min': 17.0, 'temp_kf': None

I would like to just have the average tempture written to a variable so I can use it in my program.

after some searching I found the following line of code:

```
average_temperature(unit='kelvin')
```

part of

```
class pyowm.webapi25.historian.Historian(station_history)
```

link to documentation: https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.webapi25.html#module-pyowm.webapi25.observation

(use ctrl +  f , search for celsius it is the first to pop up)

I have no clue how to use that function for the average temperature.

Anyone who can help a starting coder :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I recently encountered the same problem, and without using the function you do not know how to use, it is easier to know how to get the data you want from the initial result!

```
 observation = self.owm.weather_at_place("Gorinchem,nl")
 w = observation.get_weather()
 temperature = w.get_temperature('celsius')
```

This will output us at this very moment: `{'temp': 8.52, 'temp_max': 10.0, 'temp_min': 7.22, 'temp_kf': None}`

But we need to understand what kind of result this is:

```
print(type(temperature))
```

This will output us the type of our result:

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Having this, we now know that we can access the values individually if we access to the key:

```
avgTemp=temperature['temp']
```

This is because the key for the avg temperature (`8.52`) is `'temp'`.

To make sure you can use this, we need to know what type it is:

```
print(type(tempMedia))
```

Which will output:

```
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

The string is formatted in a way that is suited to initialize a a python dict.

```
s = "'temp': 18.72, 'temp_max': 20.0, 'temp_min': 17.0, 'temp_kf': None"
data = eval('{{{}}}'.format(s))
print data['temp']
```

Note that I added a missing `'` to the beginning of the string.
Be warned that the use of `eval` is usually considered a security risk because the string could contain malicious python code that might get executed when calling eval.

Another way would be to improve the parsing of the string using a regular expression, e.g. you could filter all decimal values and rely on the fact that the value you are looking for is always at a certain position:

```
import re
s = "'temp': 18.72, 'temp_max': 20.0, 'temp_min': 17.0, 'temp_kf': None"
temperatures = [float(q) for q in re.findall(r'([\d\.]+)', s)]
```

Comment: I know what API I am using, and I dont think it will be malicious. so the security risk of eval is none right?

Comment: @AntonvanderWel I guess so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem an unreliable way. I converted the output into a string.
Then I just pulled the characters I needed. In the end I combined them together. 
Its a ugly way, but atleast I can continue. if anyone knows a better solution go ahead!

```
s = "temp': 18.72, 'temp_max': 20.0, 'temp_min': 17.0, 'temp_kf': None"


h1 =s[7]
h2 =s[8]
k1=s[10]
print(h1+h2+","+k1)
```

Comment: Check what I just wrote!